# Unable to install application deployed with ClickOnce in Visual Studio 2015 (stdole.dll)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, stdole

Application is running in .net 4.5, built and deployed with ClickOnce in VS 2012.
When build and deploy same application, without changing any settings in VS 2015, 
I am unable to install it on client side ?

Got following error:

**"Strong name signature not valid for this assembly stdole.dll"**

When I exclude stdole.dll from deployment installation is ok.

My question is: How to deploy application in VS2015 with stdole.dll included ?