# ClickOnce installation error when publishing with VS2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

Earlier I used VS2013 to publish a windows application and the clickonce installation worked fine. 
But recently we upgraded to VS2015 and when I am publishing the same project and installing the clickonce aplication, I am getting this error

> Strong name signature not valid for this assembly stdole.dll

Could anyone please help me . I am a novice developer and so struggling to figure out what is the actual problem.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly adding *stdole.dll* to your project? It seems likely that you are now building against a version of this DLL that is not yet on your client machines.

Comment: Have you worked your way through these two links?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb94w1t5.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228671.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @PieterGeerkens , I just checked after ur answer. Actually in VS'13, if i check the ApplicationFiles under the publish tab, I see that stdole.dll as prerequisite(Auto) for the publish status and stdole.dll is not copied in the deployment folder but  in VS2015 stdole.dll is automatically set to Include(auto) and Downloadgroup col as (required), so it is being copied in the publishing folder and when installing it is checking for the stdole.dll and generating the strong name sign exception. I currently changed the setting not to include stdole.dll while publishing. Thank you for replying quickly

Comment: @PieterGeerkens , So I  basically excluded the stdole.dll while publishing from VS2015. I am not really sure what is the importance of stdole.dll as i can see the file in the project references but in VS2013 it is not included while publishing but my winform application is running fine after installing the clickonce setup file. I see similar question later but I don't see any answer for that. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019682/unable-to-install-application-deployed-with-clickonce-in-visual-studio-2015-std)